# Scatterplot comparing two variables with ggplot and tidy data

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr

With [untidy data](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html), running a scatterplot comparing two variables is trivial in either base R or `ggplot2`. For example, here is a sample scatterplot from [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/exploratory-data-analysis.html):

```
ggplot(data = faithful) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = eruptions, y = waiting))
```

[image: Wait times vs eruptions for Old Faithful]

With a tidy version of the data, though, it's unclear how to plot eruption length against wait time except as a numeric variable against a categorical variable (e.g., as in a boxplot, or point and line plot below).

Obviously, one could work with the original "wide" version or, in other cases, use the `spread` command but I wonder if I'm missing a straightforward way to assign `x` and `y` values by sub-group in `ggplot`? Or, alternatively, is this a good example of one limitation of tidy data and a use case for wide data?

```
tidy_faithful <- faithful %>%
  mutate(pair = row_number() %>%   # create pair number
                  as.factor()) %>% # make categorical
tidyr::gather(
          eruptions:waiting,
          key   = "event",
          value = "time") %>%
arrange(pair)

> head(tidy_faithful, 4)
  pair     event   time
1    1 eruptions  3.600
2    1   waiting 79.000
3    2 eruptions  1.800
4    2   waiting 54.000


tidy_faithful %>%
  slice(1:50) %>% # simplify data
  ggplot() +
    aes(x     = factor(event),
        y     = time,
        group = pair) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_line()
```

[image: paired point and line plot with tidy Old Faithful data]

Comment: I disagree that gathering this data is tidier. Perhaps if you add a `key` column first so that each eruption is still linked. But "a straightforward way to assign x and y values by sub-group" is not a plotting problem, it's data manipulation problem, so don't look for a solution *within* ggplot.

Comment: You're right that these data should be thought of as paired and that changes how the data should be gathered. I'll adjust the tidy code. There are a specific set of principles to define tidy data, however, and these data definitely violate it. See: https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf or https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html

Comment: I'm not so sure, the original format seems tidy to me -- each observation has one row, and each variable (eruptions or waiting) has a column.

Comment: @JonSpring The original data are definitely not tidy. First, the "pair" information is stored implicitly as a row number but not explicitly as a cell in the data frame. Second, the event information (waiting, eruption) is stored as column headers and not in the data frame. Put another way, there are two events per row in the original data and we cannot know by looking just within the row which event is which. Compare to the tidied version and you'll see that after gathering, both the pair number and event type are explicitly linked to a value within the data frame.

Comment: Knowing that data entries in the same row are related even if there isn't a "row number" column isn't untidy data. I could see arguments being made both ways about the `weighting` and `eruption` column. And your question seems to be an good example of the argument that it's *already tidy*. I'm glad you're enthusiastic about tidy data, it's an excellent principle---but I think you are taking it too far. Perhaps look at other *already tidy* data sets, like `diamonds` or `iris`. They are good examples of already tidy data. It's okay to have multiple columns.

Comment: @Gregor, 1/ As you noted in your first reply, the data is implicitly paired with no explicit recording of that information. Storing relevant information in row names or column headers is a quintessential messy data issue. 2/ More importantly, the question posed above is not can tidy data have multiple columns. The question is given any data in the long / tidy format shown above, is there way to plot the pairs in a scatterplot? So, to be clear, I'm not "enthusiastic" about tidy data, I'm trying to understand how one might work with edge case short of using tidyr::spread.

Comment: The "grammar of graphics" approach is to map variables to aesthetics, so ggplot2 works best when the different dimensions of your data are in different columns. If you want to map eruptions to waiting, and you are thinking of those as being two attributes of each observed eruption cycle, those should be placed into separate variables prior to ggplot. I am not aware of a good way to accomplish that otherwise.

Comment: You seem to think "long" and "tidy" are the same. While *most* untidy data is too wide, that is not the only way for data to be untidy.

Comment: There is not a good way to do what you want to do with your ultra-long data in `ggplot`. You could do it fairly easily in base R graphics. (It is generally easier to work with un-tidy data in base R graphics). `ggplot` works much better with `tidy` data, where each column represents a variable, and variables are generally things that you want to map to aesthetic dimensions. If you want `waiting` on one axis and `eruption` on another, that indicates that those should be separate columns of your data. So, your best bet is to use `spread` to tidy your data back the way it was.